# The meaning of the rundll32 command

Tags: windows, cmd, rundll32

`rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler https://bsu.by`

What does each word mean and why does it eventually open this link in the default browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather old utility that loads a DLL (with `LoadLibrary`), finds an exported function (`GetProcAddress`), makes its best guess about the expected parameter types from the looks of its command line, and invokes said function. In this case, since there's one parameter and it's not a number, rundll would assume - a single string (LPCWSTR).